# Android can't read iPhone recorded audio files

Tags: iphone, audio, avfoundation, android-mediaplayer

I record some Audio file with my iOS application and I send it to an Android application through my web server.
The Android application successfully gets the file but when I use the MediaPlayer class to try and play it, it reports an error "Unable to to create media player" at the line `mediaplayer.setDataSource(androidFilePath);`
Just to mention, iOS devices can read the files sent with the app.
After some research I found that it may be an encoding issue. But I tried many recording settings provided here on SO but none has worked. Here is the code I use to record the audio file:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

        [recordSettings NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMin] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = paths[0];
    self.audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", basePath]];


    NSError *error = nil;
    self.audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:self.audioURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if ([self.audioRecorder recordForDuration:60] == YES){
        [self.audioRecorder record];
    }
```

Could you just tell me what change do I have to make so that Android devices can read those audio files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the AVEncoderAudioQualityKey from the code and check if this solves the problem. Also do check if the android device you are checking with are able to play the other aac files properly or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably try .aac or .mp4 instead of .caf.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually it now works on most Android devices but not all. Is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't state's all the formats used [Check here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

You would have to convert to AAC or WAV before you can use it